# Total upload speed is slower when all connections are accepted by one TcpListener

Tags: c#, performance, sockets, tcplistener

I've recently encountered a strange situation in **C# .NET Framework 4.0**:

---

In a simple program, i create a TcpListener, specify its local port, start it and use async accept function to receive incoming connection requests.

Once it has pending connections inbound, the server accepts the TcpClient from async callback function and record it into a container (to be more specified, a `List<TcpClient>`).

And I write another simple client program which just connects to the server once it starts and then calls async receive function.

After all clients are connected, the server starts a group of parallel tasks using `System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach()`.

In each task, i use the TcpClient stored in that list to send data to the corresponding client. all TcpClients are sending data at the same time (I checked the client-side and they are all receiving data). The data is just a `byte[8192]` with random data generated when the server program starts. I make the server sending it repeatedly.

The client's receive callback is simple. Once data arrives, the client just ignores the data and run another async receive function.

The test environment is a **1Gbps LAN**, **one server** and **several clients**.

The result is: no matter how many clients (**from 3 ~ 8**) are connected to the server, the server's total upload speed never exceeds `13MByte/`s.

---

Then i tried another way:

I create a **TcpListener** at **client-side** also. Once the client connects to the server, the server will connect to the client's listening port also. Then the server will store this **outgoing** connection into the list instead of the incoming one.

This time, the test result changes a lot: when 3 clients are receiving data from the server, the total upload speed of server is nearly `30MByte/s`; with 5 clients, the total upload speed goes up to nearly `50MBytes/s`.

Though this `10MByte/s-per-client` limit may due to hardware or network configuration, it is still far much better than the case above.

---

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the cause of this behavior, but as a workaround I suggest sending much bigger buffers. Like 1MB (or at least 64k). On a 1Gbps LAN you are likely to be more efficient if your app is sending bigger chunks (and less packets). Also, enable jumbo frames.

Comment: I just tried both bigger socket send/recv buffer size and bigger data chunk. Unfortunately no joy. And how to enable jumbo frames?

Comment: Google: Enable jumbo frames ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the instruction. However it's impossible for me to enable jumbo frames in my network environment, the network adapter doesn't support this feature, neither does the switch.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use threads or Tasks for the processing. It will hurt your performance.

I've made a framework which will help you develop performant networking applications whithout having to care about the actual IO processing.

http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/05/griffin-networking-a-somewhat-performant-networking-library-for-net/